# onpropertychange detect user action

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

To detect change in a textbox,I have to use "onpropertychange" in IE("oninput" for others)
"onpropertychange" acts quite like "oninput",but it is also triggerd by non-user behavior.
is there a way to find wether the "onpropertychange" is triggerd by user action(listed below)

- keyboard input
- cut
- delete
- paste
- selected from dropdown tipbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your best bet is to use a wrapper function to change your text box's value.

**[EDIT: It's possible to do it in IE 8 and above using a getter and setter. See @AndyE's comment]**

Live demo (IE only): http://jsfiddle.net/4C6KL/

Code:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("foo");
var changingValue = false;

textBox.onpropertychange = function() {
    if (window.event.propertyName == "value" && !changingValue) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
};

function setTextBoxValue(val) {
    changingValue = true;
    textBox.value = val;
    changingValue = false;
}
```

Comment: +1, though in IE 8 & 9, you could proxy the property descriptor for `HTMLInputElement#value` and `HTMLElement.setAttribute`, which would cover any cases where the value of the element was changed by script, apart from resetting, perhaps.  Doesn't help for IE 7 and lower, though.  EDIT: [Very basic example using your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/4C6KL/1/) (IE8/9 only).

Comment: @AndyE: Good point. I forget that IE 8 supports that. IE 9 has the `input` event, of course.

Comment: wrapper costs too much,for ie 6&7,I will just check whether the srcElement has focus.